# Accented character MAC to Windows

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, character-encoding

While working in a team where members use both MAC and Windows machines, sharing code using GIT, SVN or even just a USB key, it appears to have character encoding problem with accented characters é, è, ê, ë, à, â, ç, ô, ù, ï, and that's only those in French.

There's no problem sharing files from PC to MAC. MAC users somehow open the file correctly, and save it in a way that `é` stays `é` for them. The problem is when a MAC user sends back the file to a PC user. In this case, where you could read `é` on a MAC, you now read `ï¿½` on Windows.

Example: `Généré` becomes `Gï¿½nï¿½rï¿½` (how horrible is that for a user or for devs reading comments!)

I want to know, once and for all and on behalf of all other developpers who have to write code in other langage than English, how do you open on Windows a file saved from a MAC without having to use search and replace. The program I use is generally Eclipse (Java), but I am also looking for a general solution since it happens in every possible coding language, even VBA. So, if it works for all other programs, it would be worth mentionning!

Comment: You need to agree on a character encoding and stick to it. UTF-8 is likely the best one. Java IDE's all have an option to set the character encoding of the editor and the compiler on a global or on a per-project basis. If you use maven to build, you can set the character encoding in the compiler plugin config in your pom.xml, and at least in Eclipse, the maven plugin for Eclipse will pick that up and configure Eclipse correctly.

Comment: Ok. I think the best would be that my entire code stays readable by humans, not only the build. That would help a lot developping. Do you happen to know what is the default encoding for a MAC so next time I won't even have to ask them?

Comment: "I think the best would be that my entire code stays readable by humans, not only the build. " - I'm not sure what you mean by that, or how that's related to my comment?

Comment: Oh I meant that from both option you seemed to suggest, it seems that the one where you set the encoding on a project basis would be enough for the needs.